# OBSOLETE - so++ - C++ Library

Tags: library, obsolete, c++

> ## Obsolete:  Coded for a decommissioned version of the API.  Source code might be adaptable though.

[image]
<sub>(source: DEAD LINK: <del>[quickmediasolutions.com](http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/sopp.png))</del></sub>

### Code Snippet

```
#include <sopp/sopp.h>

...
sopp::SetKey("...");
sopp::SetSite(SITE_STACKOVERFLOW);
...
sopp::soUser user(1);
cout << user.GetDisplayName();
...
std::vector<sopp::soQuestion> questions;
user.GetQuestions(questions);

cout << questions[0].GetTitle();  // display title of first question
...
```

### About

so++ is an object-oriented wrapper for the StackOverflow API. It currently uses libcurl and jsoncpp. The .zip file includes examples, though they need the API key replaced.

#### License

so++ is released under the MIT license.

#### Download

You can download so++ at <del>http://stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/</del> (Dead link)

**Update:** the code is now in my PPA, so you can get it there if you're using Ubuntu:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:george-edison55/george-edison

#### Platform

so++ is available for any platform with libcurl and the STL.

### Contact

I am the developer and can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com

### Code

The code can now be found on LaunchPad: http://launchpad.net/sopp

Comment: nice work again!!

Comment: **About** say it uses jsoncpp, but **Platform** seems to suggest it doesn't. ;)

Comment: @KTC: jsoncpp has the same requirements as my wrapper and will therefore run on anything that my wrapper runs on.

Comment: Now on Launchpad: http://launchpad.net/sopp

Comment: Is this still being developed? How to submit patches?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not currently - but patches are welcome. Please visit the Launchpad page for so++ here: https://launchpad.net/sopp

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Hmm, it's too tricky to submit patches. I simplified the two makefiles, though: [jsoncpp](http://pastebin.com/u2u4xyhv) and [sopp](http://pastebin.com/FhPU2SmE).

Comment: Don't know much yet about the stack API but I noticed it says v1 is obsolete and this was made before v2 release.  Is it still usable.  I wanted to use for a blackberry playbook app.  This would be perfect for me to practice with if so.

Comment: @BrandonClark: Yes, that is correct. so++ supported a limited set of requests against v1.0 of the API and as such should still work.