# Do we have a C++ wrapper library for SO API?

Tags: discussion

- I wanted to develop a SO app, and I have no prior web programming experience.
- I know C, C++ and a bit of Perl.

Is there an wrapper for the API in one of these languages?
If not, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. A list of libraries can be found here: [List of API client libraries grouped by programming language](https://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-libraries).

[Someone suggested](https://stackapps.com/questions/1453/add-list-of-libraries-to-get-started-sidebar) that link be placed in the side bar, but apparently no one with the juice to make it happen thinks that is a good idea.

Comment: For the record, I thought it was a great idea.

Comment: Yes, it should be definitely there in the side bar, would have saved me a day.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a C++ wrapper. You can find details about it here:

[so++ - C++ Library](https://stackapps.com/questions/25/)

Comment: you wrote the *only* c++ client library.

Comment: One doubt - Once I am able to fetch the results using your API, how do I convert the thing into an "app" can can be used from a browser?

Comment: @Lazer: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please ignore my comment for now. I'll try things out.